# Sign of the Cross – case of “Im Namen”

Tags: grammatical-case, article

In English, the words used when making the Sign of the Cross are:

> In the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit. Amen.

The German translation is:

> Im Namen des Vaters und des Sohnes […]

While I understand that the possessive *der Vater* takes the genitive case as *des Vaters.* I don’t understand why *der Name*, which is possessed by *der Vater,* takes what appears to be the dative case definitive article *dem* and an additional *n.* Is *Namen* plural, and if so, shouldn’t the article therefore be *den?*

Comment: Are you asking "why is *Namen* in dative" or are you asking "why is it *Namen* instead of *Name*"?

Comment: Tofro, I'm asking both questions which have been kindly answered by both yourself and sgf.

Answer (score 15):

The preposition **in** in German always governs two cases, meaning it can take both the accusative and the dative cases, but not all at once, of course.

> As a general rule, **in + accusative** is used when the whole construction expresses *direction* (equivalent to the English **into**), and **in + dative** is used when it expresses *position* (equivalent to the English **in**).

So, naturally, **in** in `in the name of the...`, **in + noun**, expresses *position*, not *direction*, which can only mean that the case that goes with this preposition is the dative. Hence, **i*m* Namen...**

Comment: Thanks User26328. Having only started learning German a few weeks ago I haven't yet dealt with prepositions. Your answer explains "in" very well. It's now making a lot much more sense.

Comment: Is this really a quote? If yes, what’s the source? If not, it would better to remove the quote markup.

Answer (score 6):

The dative for "Name" is simply caused by the preposition "in" (or "in dem", pulled together to "im") which can either rule the accusative (for movements towards something) or dative (for movements within a specified area or static location).

Here "Im (in dem) Namen" is static, so the name must be dative. The fact that the name is owned by the father causes (in an unrelated way) the possesive genitive.

Comment: Der OP fragt nach *N-Deklination*, glaube ich. In der Frage ist der Schluss, dass er nicht versteht, woher das -n stammt. Er denkt der Buchstabe gehöre zum Plural, was aber nicht unbedingt der Fall bei schwachen Nomen sein muss.

Comment: @c.p. der OP scheint zu wissen, dass das -n zusammen mit dem Artikel "dem" auf den Dativ hinweist - Aber nicht warum. Aber - kann sein...

Comment: Wenn so,  warum vermutet er dann am Ende, dass *Namen* im Plural steht? Meine Antwort wäre: weil er denkt, dass die Endung *nur* dem Dativ Plural gehören kann.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I'm only weeks not my German language journey and have only learnt the most basic and general information about the cases. It will be a long but satisfying adventure, I'm sure.

Answer (score 4):

*Der Name* is (as either most or all masculine nouns ending in -e) a **weak noun**. Weak masculine nouns get an *-en* at the end of the word in all cases but the nominative, except that some of them (including *Name*) take *-ens* in the genitive case. Thus the dative case (which is required after *in**) singular of *der Name* is *dem Namen*, and *in dem* is contracted to *im*.

*<sub>If *in* is used to denote a direction rather than a location (i.e. corresponds to English *into*),  it requires the Accusative case.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Sehr einfach:

> Nominativ: **der Name**
>
> Genitiv: **des Namens**
>
> Dativ: **dem Namen**
>
> Akkusativ: **den Namen**

*In* im Sinne von *wo?* verlangt den Dativ. (*In* im Sinne von *wohin?* würde dagegen den Akkusativ verlangen.)

Auf Kosten des Hauses hier noch die Pluralformen:

> Nominativ: **die Namen**
>
> Genitiv: **der Namen**
>
> Dativ: **den Namen**
>
> Akkusativ: **die Namen**

Comment: Danke Christian.